# Error when call contract method on binance smart chain

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets, hardhat

when a i call any of contract methods (the contract is the pancakeswap factory), this error return
**error: call revert exception (method="allPairsLength()", errorSignature=null, errorArgs=[null], reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.0.13)**
Anyone know why?

```
const hre = require ('hardhat');

async function main() {

  const provider = new hre.ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
  console.log(await provider.getBalance('0xDf5390a504263d35Db42E1Df19775b6855C548af'));
  factory = await hre.ethers.getContractAt('IUniswapV2Factory','0xBCfCcbde45cE874adCB698cC183deBcF17952812');
  await factory.allPairsLength()
  
}

main();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details, including what you are trying to achieve and how (with code).

Answer (score 1):

The line `factory = await hre.ethers.getContractAt('IUniswapV2Factory','0xBCf..12')` references the contract on hardhat network. While I think you mean to connect to a contract on bsc.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------v
factory = await hre.ethers.getContractAt('IUniswapV2Factory','0xBCf..12', provider)
```

Just need to add the provider there, then your `factory.allPairsLength()` call should be made on bsc instead of hardhat network